# ajax requesting POST error status code 500

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

i have a controller that have a methods for my ajax request

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function (e) {
    var array = {
        some data
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.origin + "/Page/ManageEmployee/Index/DataInsert",
        type: "POST",
        data: array,
        
        success: function (response) {
            var result = $(response).find('#body').html();
            console.log(response);
            $('#body').html(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error_m) {
            alert(status + error_m);
        }
    });
});
```

this is my ajax code, i have three ajax code all of them are the same way of requesting ajax request, the differences only are in the url.

for actiona name Delete

> url: window.location.origin + "/Page/ManageEmployee/Index/Delete"

for action name Insert_Something

> url: window.location.origin + "/Page/ManageEmployee/Index/Insert_Something"

for DataInsert Actiona Name in the controller that did not work or error

> url: window.location.origin + "/Page/ManageEmployee/Index/DataInsert"

**This the code of my controller in the project**

> I put a debugger on the method that does not run and when executing
> the program or system it didnt jump in the DataInsert method, because
> there is an ajax error:
>
> > "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
> > ()"

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int index)
{
 //this method run
}
                
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Insert_Something(ModelClass data)
{
 //this method run
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DataInsert(ModelClass data)
{
 //this method doesn't run
}
```

**The Question or My problem is:**

> how can i fix the error in requesting a post method into my controller, or what seems the problem because the other ajax request works but the ajax with url: DataInsert not work

Additional:
Im new to using the ASP.NET MVC so my code structure or the way I work things might be weird to others, just learning this framework by relying on the post in internet, yt and some free resources in the internet. If something you can advise or give tips to make my structure be better or best practices i can change to improve my code.

Comment: is your question about 500 int server error or you need suggestions on better approach?

Comment: oh sorry the main question here should be what seems the problem in my ajax code requesting  a post method

Comment: As @TheGodfather said, the troubleshooting should go to the server. Your method that doesn't work is throwing some error. Reading the error is the key!

Comment: it's not that I had this issue an hour ago and then posted it here.  I read the error and did my research, I'm finding a solution to my problem for over a day now, and post it because i feel like i hit a wall because there is no progress. This is the only error shown on the console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()"

Comment: Place a breakpoint in your endpoint, does it get hit? If so, start debugging. A 500 error is a server error, so code is breaking in our endpoint (or just before it).

Comment: i place a breakpoint at the method that does not run, and when i execute the program, when clicking the button the method in the controller is not getting hit. It directs to error in ajax @Olaf

Comment: You ajax request URL is not correct , if you are using asp.net core MVC api controller , your URL should be YourHostName/Controller/Action for instance `http://localhost:5062/ManageEmployee/Insert_Something`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, the url (url: window.location.origin + "/Page/ManageEmployee/Index/DataInsert") is equivalent to (http : //localhost:44399/Page/ManageEmployee/Index/DataInsert). And I already configure this the route. And im using ASP.NET MVC not with core, i dont know what is the difference but yeah

Comment: Incorrect however, I am writing the sample for you wait a while. How did you configured the route?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, like this (
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "PageEmployee",
                url: "Page/ManageEmployee/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Index", action ="Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
                namespaces: new[] { "PayrollWeb.Controllers.Page.ManageEmployee" }
                );).      it is kinda hard to read here

Comment: Based on your route configuration, I think its generating incorrect URL. Try out the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Im new to using the ASP.NET MVC so my code structure or the way I work
> things might be weird to others, just learning this framework by
> relying on the post in internet, yt and some free resources in the
> internet. If something you can advise or give tips to make my
> structure be better or best practices i can change to improve my code.

Based on your shared code snippet and according to your route defination, its quite obvious that, your ajax URL is incorrect. The way you have configured the route which generating invalid URL for reaching the API controller endpoint.

Request Model:

```
public class ModelClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

Let's say, you have following API controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ManageEmployeeController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Insert_Something")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Insert_Something(ModelClass searchModel)
    {

        return Ok(searchModel);
    }
}
```

Ajax Request Format:

In order to submit request to above controller, you should decorate your ajax request as following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function (e) {

    const array = { Id: 1, Name: "Test Name" };
    var data = JSON.stringify(array);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Api/ManageEmployee/Insert_Something',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (e) {
        }
    });
});
```

**Note:** Also `window.location.origin +'/Api/ManageEmployee/Insert_Something'` also correct.

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you have any specific requirement for [custom route configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#problems-with-route-value-invalidation), please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#problems-with-route-value-invalidation).

Comment: im using asp.net mvc not asp.net core, idont know what is the difference but if i applied it in my project i should put data annotation on the top of the method? Is it necessary to use json even im not working with api?

Comment: Well, asp.net MVC is a older version which is not supported any more. I am recommeding you to start with asp.net core newer version even asp.net core 3.2 out of support, because in version 8 has not of updated and performence improvement stuff. Regarding the annoration, if you have both MVC and WEB API project within one project then need to define the annotation on top of API controller. Because I am using .NET 8 I don't need any additional route defination in program.cs file.

Comment: So I only need to use `[Route("Insert_Something")]`  on top on my Web API controller as I have both API controller and MVC controller within  same project. Thus, I need to use  `[Route("Insert_Something")]` on action.

Comment: do you think one of the problem to consider here is that im using multiple ajax in one controller?

Comment: Not sure, what do you mean by "multiple ajax in one controller", we can use  many ajax request from various route to call the controller. Still need to check your details what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i got the error now thanks to your sample picture with the preview tab i got error of (No parameterless constructor defined for this object.)

Comment: No worries, I hope that helped you. Feel free to let me know if you need any further assistnace on this.